# DLL self-registration: how to register just for the current user?

Tags: visual-c++, com, registry, registration

I'm using Visual C++. I'd like to really only have the DLL registered for the current user, even if the users is an administrator.

For that reason, I changed all of the `project.rgs` references to HKCR.
But, using Process Monitor while using `regsvr32` to register the DLL, I notice that it still tries to create `HKCR\TypeLib\{ ... }`.
This happens on the call to `CComModule::RegisterServer()`.

Is this inherent of `CComModule`? Is there anything I'm missing, in terms of configuration of Visual C++? I know that I can use `RegOverridePredefKey`, but I don't want to load more DLLs, and it's not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

`CComModule::RegisterServer()` has a `BOOL` first parameter that indicates whether it should register the type library. Set it to `FALSE` and it will not try to.

Comment: The BOOL parameter in RegisterServer(..) is if to register the typelib, not to control the per user.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This parameter controls whether the code for registering the typeplib will be invoked. The OP's problem is that after his .rgs file is rolled into the registry the code for registering typlib is also invoked and rolls in the "HKCR\TypeLib\{Something} key.

Comment: Well, I don't want to *not* register it. I just want to make it register in `HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib`.

Comment: No problem - specify FALSE to RegisterServer() and insert the necessary statement to the .rgs file. I guess it'll be clearer if you set a breakpoint and then step into RegisterServer() - it calls UpdateRegistry() for the COM exposed classes and then registers a typelib in a standard way (in HKCR) if the first parameter is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

HKCR is not mapped to the current user registry hive, if you really want to register the server for the local user use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` instead of HKCR.